# Object property change its value itself (or it seems like so)

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have a function that transforms property in an object from Date type to the string with `.getTime()` method. It works well, I can see, that my prop and object is OK, but at the moment when I send the result to the server, it converts my string to date object back.

```
    const temp = this.committeeInfo.aDatesPhases.map((item): IDatesPhases => {
      return {
        ...item,
        sDateStart: String(Number(new Date(item.sDateStart).getTime())),
        sDateEnd: String(Number(new Date(item.sDateEnd).getTime()))
      };
    });
    this.committeeData = {
      ...this.committeeData,
      aDatesPhases: temp
    };
    console.log(this.committeeData.aDatesPhases); // Works fine

    this._store.dispatch(new AddCommitteePending(this.committeeData)); // There aDatesPhases now just dates again
```

NgRx Effect just sends it to the server, not modify, reducer for action only changes state to loading indication.

What can be the problem and how can I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try using object.assign to change the object properties instead of mere assigning something like,

```
this.committeeData= Object.assign({}, this.committeeData, {aDatesPhases: temp});
```

In your code, you are changing the inner object aDatesPhases's reference but not updating the reference of aDatesPhases to this.committeeData, i believe so.